# Is there way to wrap bash commands in the same way the time builtin does?

Tags: bash

So the `time` builtin in bash can do `time ls | sleep 2` and it will time not just `ls` but also the `sleep 2`. Essentially it takes the entire line including the pipe as its argument.

I would like to do the same, but if I define a function say `wrapit` and invoke `wrapit ls | sleep 2`, it will call `wrapit` with 'ls' and then `sleep 2` separately. Is there a way to define a function such that it takes the entire rest of the line as its argument?

I think there might be a solution using [some bash-preexec hacking](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec), but there are a lot of issues to work through there. Hoping I am missing something simpler.

Comment: I don't really see any useful uses of such a hack; what use case do you have in mind?

Comment: I've definitely seen lots of use cases, but then, I come from a functional programming background -- function composition is thus a regular building block. Think about doing something like `run-for-each hosts.txt command-to-run` -- sometimes you'll want your `command-to-run` to be a compound command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I think the danger here is that with such a generic example, we're in danger of this being an XY problem. While it's great to have a small example, it's also really useful to have larger context so that we can help people *apply* tools better.

Comment: That's a fair concern.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: don't use the wrong paradigm in the wrong language. What if someone comes from OO? or from LP? they'll want to do their OO or LP in shells? that's just not right.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, heh. There's a point when FP becomes the wrong paradigm, but that point is when you're doing `eval` hackery to get semantics that languages built for functional programming would give you for free. We're not there right now. :)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, ...at some point I'll need to rebuild and release the toolchain I built (for frontend use from shell) for expressing parallel operations / orchestration at a former employer. It included primitives for things like iterating over hosts in the same load balancer, and grabbing locks in a shared Zookeeper repository -- so you could write a command line that had a structure like `iteratively-for-each-pool if-all-systems-are-healthy in-parallel-for-each-host with-lock upgrade-node`, or such with each of those being a separate function or command. It was darned handy in practice.

Comment: ...I'm eliding a lot of capabilities there -- support for variables to pass context around through the tree, helpers that could deal with complex conditions (ie. ensuring that a pool never lost a quorum of healthy nodes), &c; the actual commands were built of smaller primitives (ie. `in-parallel-for-each-host` was built on a `parallel-for`, with an argument telling it how to get the list to iterate over).

Comment: Back towards the question: There may well be a *literal* answer that involves a loadable module (written in C), but I'm inclined to call that cheating. If the OP doesn't agree as to "cheating" and would accept an answer in that family, follow up, and I may consider putting the effort to build it. Maybe.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf The use case I have in mind is to create a logger of sorts. It would automatically tee the output off to somewhere in tmp, and a rerun of the command would utilize the same output so it doesn't have to be recalculated.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't consider a loadable module to be cheating. tbh I didn't know that was a thing before just now, I'll have to look more into it. I think it would be preferable to the solution I was considering (bash prexec hack handling all commands and cancelling/rewriting them).

Comment: So this is a logger for in-pipeline content, to allow a resume with previously-generated content for successful pipeline components even if later components fail? Frankly, this kind of hackery seems like severe overkill, if that's all you want to do.

Comment: ...I have a few ideas I could spitball, but a detailed description of the problem you're trying to accomplish -- posed as its own, separate StackOverflow question -- might be the better forum. To be clear, I have a strong dislike for magic and a preference for explicit syntax, so I might not give you what you want in terms of a single-command prefix that does what you're asking for with no other changes, but if what you care about is getting your problem solved, vs getting your problem solved with the level of magic requested here, that's a thing I can work with.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I will consider that, though I think I will take another crack at it on my own now that I know loadable modules is an option. Might still be/probably is an xy problem in that this magic may not be the syntax I settle on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time` is technically not a command, but a pipeline modifier (that is, it is as much as part of the syntax of a pipe as the `|` is), which is why it is able to work the way it does. With a function, the best you can do is pass a *string* as a single argument, and use `eval`:

```
# Trivial example that is similar to eval alone
wrapit () {
   eval "$1"
}

wrapit "ls | sleep 2"
```

Comment: Nicely done; in terms of syntax, `time` is a _keyword_ (`type time`).

Comment: Am not sure I understand it, can you explain it a bit more on what output is expected of above, it is producing an empty result for me.

Comment: @Inian `ls | sleep 2` doesn't have any output either.

Comment: @chepner: I thought OP's requirement was to evaluate the first argument and treat rest of the argument as separate. In which case I expected to see the o/p of `ls`

Comment: @Inian No; `time ls | sleep 2` times the *entire* pipeline, not just `ls`. The pipeline is the "argument" to `time`.

Comment: @Inian .. also, the entire output of the pipeline is the output of the last command in the pipeline, so with `ls` piped into `sleep`, which produces no output, you should expect to see no results other than the delay.

Comment: This answer and the comment from @mklement0 help illustrate best that what I asked for is not really possible, as `time` is itself *very* special. I looked into the bash source code and it is in fact not even a 'command', but a keyword handled along the lines of 'if' and 'else'. As far as I can tell, the behavior I asked for would not even be possible with a loadable module, but would actually require a modified bash.

Answer (score 4):

I use function wrappers all the time, and my experience is that the best-practice approach is to wrap your pipelines in a function.

```
# some random wrapper -- in this case, eliminating command output unless successful
emit_only_on_success() {
  local output
  output=$( "$@" ) && printf '%s\n' "$output"
}

myfunc() { ls | sleep 2; }
emit_only_on_success myfunc
```

This way you can use your wrappers for pipelines, as opposed to simple commands only.